# codeigniter method chaining not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
var dtGetName = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata['sesSearch']['pro_name'] ?>";
```

---

javascript
:::::
output: ReferenceError: $ is not defined

what's wrong??

Comment: At what page are you using this PHP code

Comment: codeigniter view page whit ajax

Comment: Ok come to the chat ill guide you through http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137124/codeigniter

Comment: chat rom no work for me

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon after echo statement and for the retrieving session,

set it like this first,

> $this->session->set_userdata('session_variable_name',$data);

and

to get the user data

> $session_data = $this->session->userdata('session_variable_name');